# Domain of a function 5

Tags: calculus

I was solving this domain:

$$ f(x)= \sqrt\frac{(e^x-2)^x + \arccos(e^x -2)}{x- \sqrt {x^2 -1}}$$

My solution is: $x^2 \geq 1$ and the argument of the first sqrt $\geq 0$ (can't solve this one) and $0 \leq x \leq \log3$ and $x \geq 2$ and the denominator $\neq 0$
Could you help me to reach the right solution?
note1: Missing the x- factor

Comment: Continuing from your steps: $x^2\ge1$ and $0 \le x \le \ln3$ so $x \ge 1$.  This guarantees $e^x-2>0$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need that

$$\sqrt {x^2 -1}\neq 0 \quad \land\quad x-\sqrt {x^2 -1} \neq0$$

$$-1 \leq e^x -2 \leq 1 \quad \land\quad  e^x -2>0 \implies 0 < e^x -2 \leq 1$$

$$\frac{(e^x-2)^x + \arccos(e^x -2)}{x-\sqrt {x^2 -1}}\ge0$$

Answer (score 0):

The necesaary conditions are :

$x^2>1$ as the denominator of the function cant be 0 ,

$e^x -2 >0$ as the function $a^x$ is defined for all real x iff a>0.

and $-1\leq e^x -2\leq 1$ for $ arccos(e^x-2)$.

and $x- \sqrt{x^2-1}>0$

Solving these conditions you will get the domain, as we can clearly see that $ arccos(e^x-2)$ and $(e^x -2)^x$ are non negative functions.

Comment: 1) x<-1 and x>1                                                                                                          2) x > log (2)                                                                                                            3) 0<= x <= log 3                                                                                                       4) x>1                                                                                                                   Is this right?

Comment: @volkov yes exactly.

Comment: My domain is nothing, the problem is the point 1 that gives me no solution in common

Comment: @volkov there will be an 'or' instead of "and'' in condition 1